# LocalStorage: Console message is not showing after 3rd click onwards

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Have requirement like, if we run this code, it will show default console message, if we run the code with in 2 mins it should show `Warning: Clicked within 2 minutes!`, this is working fine in the code. If we run the same code again within 2 mins console message is not giving. Kindly help me the issue. For me if we run any number of times within 2 mins message should show always and if we run the code after 2 mins only default message should come.

```
const lastClickedTime = localStorage.getItem('lastClickedTime');
const currentTime = new Date();
const warningLogged = localStorage.getItem('warningLogged');

if (lastClickedTime && currentTime.getTime() - Number(lastClickedTime) <= 120000) {
  if (!warningLogged) {
    console.log('Warning: Clicked within 2 minutes!');
    localStorage.setItem('warningLogged', 'true');
  }
} else {
  console.log('Default message:', currentTime);
  localStorage.removeItem('warningLogged');
}

localStorage.setItem('lastClickedTime', String(currentTime.getTime()));
```

Comment: Your 'Warning' console message is not showing second time because you have wrapped that inside the condition `!warningLogged`. This is expected as first time this variable is set in the localstorage.

Comment: Sidenote - Nothing to do with Typescript, Angular, html. Please remove these tags.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment. This is expected behaviour as you are wrapping message show in a condition which is getting set in the first run.

to fix this you can just comment the condition and it will show the warning message everytime you run the function within two minutes.

```
const lastClickedTime = localStorage.getItem('lastClickedTime');
const currentTime = new Date();
const warningLogged = localStorage.getItem('warningLogged');

if (lastClickedTime && currentTime.getTime() - Number(lastClickedTime) <= 120000) {
  //if (!warningLogged) {
    console.log('Warning: Clicked within 2 minutes!');
    localStorage.setItem('warningLogged', 'true');
  //}
} else {
  console.log('Default message:', currentTime);
  localStorage.removeItem('warningLogged');
}

localStorage.setItem('lastClickedTime', String(currentTime.getTime()));
```

And that being said you don't need warningLogged state unless you are using it elsewhere.